# xsl:template match attribute: how related to default namespace

Tags: xslt, xpath, namespaces

I encountered a peculiar difference in xslt behavior when the root element has a default namespace attribute as opposed to when it does not.
I am wondering why this difference occurs.

The XML input is

```
<root>
    <content>xxx</content>
</root>
```

When the following transformation is applied

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="content">
        <w>x</w>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the result is the expected

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <w>x</w>
</root>
```

But when the same transformation is applied to

```
<root xmlns="http://test.com">
    <content>xxx</content>
</root>
```

the result is different and based on the application of just default templates (which effectively output the text node value 'xxx'):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>xxx</root>
```

**Addition**

When this is the expected behavior in this case, then what match attribute value is needed to match the `content` element in the second case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so what exactly is your question?  If you're simply looking for an explanation, following is a brief one.  What you're observing is the proper behavior according to the specification.  When you put a namespace on something, the parser essentially treats it as a different element entirely (than an element of the same name but no namespace).  Therefore, in the second situation, when you say `<xsl:template match="content">`, it doesn't match the `<content>` element in the XML file because it falls under the `http://test.com` namespace (by way of the namespace declaration on its parent).  Therefore, the default templates take over.

Comment: OK sounds clear although a little unexpected - an additional question then: how match the `content` element in the second case?

Comment: fyi there are a couple ways to match the element with the namespace. One way would be to add it to your XSL declaration, i.e. `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:myNS="http://test.com">`, in which case you would have to change your template match statement to `<xsl:template match="myNS:content">`. Or, you can simply change your template match statement to `<xsl:template match="*[local-name() = content]">`

Comment: Oops forgot the quotes, in my last sentence the word content should be surrounded by apostrophes, i.e. 'content'

Comment: Clear again - the second alternative was one I thought of already, but looked a little overdone to me - I should have mentioned that, scusi. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Maestro13 - If you're using XSLT 2.0, you can also use `*` as the prefix: `match="*:content"`

Answer (score 5):

**This is the most FAQ in XPath / XSLT**.

An unprefixed element name is treated by XPath as belonging to "no namespace".

**The [W3C Xpath specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#node-tests) says**:

> if the QName does not have a prefix, then the namespace URI is null.

Therefore, in a document with a default namespace a refernce to an element with unprefixed name (say "someName") selects nothing, because there isn't any element in "no namespace" in the XML document, but `someName` means an element with name "someName", belonging to "no namespace".

**The Solution**:

If we want to select an element by name, we must prefix that name and the prefix must be associated with the default namespace.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:x="http://test.com" exclude-result-prefixes="x">
        <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <root>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </root>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="x:content">
            <w>x</w>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document with default namespace:**

```
<root xmlns="http://test.com">
    <content>xxx</content>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<root>
   <w>x</w>
</root>
```

Comment: Yes - should have known that a default namespace changes things - I guess I just thought that only non-default ones would necessitate prefixing the element name (or using `local-name()`).

Comment: @Maestro13: This is a rule to remember: If a default namespace is used, then to select a particular element, whose name is unprefixed in the XML document, we must prefix it in the XPath expression. I have edited my answer and now, in addition to the complete transformation, I provide the exact quote from the W3C XPath specification, and a link to the section containing that text.

Comment: I now remember this one coming by a month ago: [namespace-stopping-xslt-working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886520/namespace-stopping-xslt-working) - finally it all makes sense to me now!

Comment: @Maestro13: Yes, there are many questions like this -- both in the "xslt" and in the "xpath tags -- almost everyday someone asks yet another question about selection with default namespace ...