# Transform fails when root element has name space

Tags: xml, xslt, reporting-services, xslt-1.0

I have a report in XML format generated by MS SQLserver report server. The root element has a namespace declaration in it as shown in the source xml code fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data xsi:schemaLocation="course http://<sqlserveraddress>/ReportServer?%7C4ke03n45bssdhbvwcrhnst45%7C%40%7C%2FPepi%2FAngus%20Development%2FPreTerm%2Fcourse%7C&amp;rs%3ACommand=Render&amp;rs%3AFormat=XML&amp;rs%3ASessionID=y14z41zpzcfdms45pz2iab55&amp;rc%3ASchema=True" 
Name="course" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="course">
<Tablix1>
<Details_Collection>
<Details action="create" fullname="The TV Commercial" Shortname="SCM147-7841" startdate="1405296000" idnum="7841" Code="SCM147" />
<Details action="create" fullname="Scoring Emotion" Shortname="SCM132-7842" startdate="1405296000" idnum="7842" Code="SCM132" />
</Details_Collection>
</Tablix1>
</data>
```

I am unable to do a transform using XLST on this xml source even when I try to declare the name space in the XLST as per the description in the following post
[Namespace Stopping XSLT Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886520/namespace-stopping-xslt-working?rq=1)

I'm using the following XLST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:course="http://<sqlserveraddress/ReportServer>">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:element name="data">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/course:Report/Tablix1/Details_Collection/Details[@action='create']">
<xsl:element name="datum" >
    <xsl:attribute name="action">create</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have tried with the full query string from the source root element namespace declaration but still no luck.

If I strip out the namespace declaration on the source XML doc then I get a transformation so the XSL works. Maybe I just don't understand the syntax of the root element namespace declaration, can anybody explain this to me?

Regards

Angus

Comment: `xmlns:course="http://<sqlserveraddress/ReportServer>">` is invalid. it must not contain the `<` character.

Comment: I should have made it clear that the <sqlserveraddress> business is a place holder for the actual server address db.domain.etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that your namespace declarations are different in your XML and you XSLT, and you are not referencing the namespaces correctly in your XSLT anyway.

In your XML you define a default namespace

```
 <data xmlns="course">
```

This means this **data** element, and all descendant nodes are part of the "course" namespace. The word course here is actually a "namespace URI".

Now in your XSLT you do this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:course="http://<sqlserveraddress/ReportServer>">
```

(I am assuming you have just used angle brackets here so as to not show you sql server name).

In this case, when you do `xmlns:course="..."` then "course" is a namespace prefix, not the namespace URI itself. The actual namespace URI is your `http://<sqlserveraddress/ReportServer>`, which differs from namespace used in the XML. The prefix can really be anything you choose, it is the namespace URI that must match. The prefix is really there as a convenience to save you writing the URI in multiple places.

When you do have namespaces, you also have to ensure the prefix is used in all elements in any xpath expression. So, you would have to do this

```
<xsl:template match="/course:Report/course:Tablix1/course:Details_Collection/course:Details[@action='create']">
```

(Of course, this is looking for a **Report** element too, which is not present in your XML).

So, in short, you probably need to change the namespace declaration in your XSLT to match the XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:course="course">
```

And then change any xpath expressions that match the source XML to use the namespace prefix as mentioned above.

Comment: Further to previous comment; in the XLST
`xmlns:course="course"` 
I have got rather confused by the 
`xsi:schemaLocation="course http://<sqlserveraddress>/ReportServer` line in the source XML as the word `course` before the actual web address is confusing what does it mean?. 
So to clarify something in my own mind, the `<data xmlns="course">` statement in the source XML, does this declare the namespace prefix or the name space URI or both ?

Comment: Doing `<data xmlns="course">` declares a 'default' namespace. `course` is still the namespace URI in this instance, but because no prefix has been specified, any element in the XML with no prefix will belong to that namespace.